# Weak convergence, weak neighborhoods

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $V$ be a normed vector space, $V'$ its continuous dual. Let $U \subset V$.

Consider the statements:

i) 
For any finite $F \subset V'$
there exists $y \in U$ with $\max_{f \in F} |f(y)| < 1$.

ii)
$U$ contains a sequence that converges weakly to zero.

Then ii) implies i). Does i) imply ii)?

Comment: I think the set $U=\{e_n+n e_m \,|\, m>n\}$ in $\ell_2$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMitra: however, i) does imply that zero is in the $\sigma(V, V')$-closure of $U$, right?

Comment: Yes. Given a weak nhood of $0$ generated by $f_1,\ldots, f_m$ and $\epsilon=1/n$, apply i) to $nf_1,\ldots, nf_m$.